# deploying a shared bin directory using mklink in IIS

Tags: .net, iis, deployment

I have 2 web-applications built-in .NET 4.0. I want to use the following folder structure while deploying into production server in IIS 6/7/7.5 (not decided yet):

> ```
> C:\Inetpub\wwwroot
> -- App1
>    -- bin (link)
> -- App2 
>    -- bin (link)
> -- bin
> ```

App1 and App2 are IIS applications running in seperate app pools. I plan to use mklink (or the xp resourec pack utility linkd) to create the bin directories.

The reason is to *not* have multiple copies of the dlls (I know I could deploy to GAC), but the build output is produced in this format, and it would be simplest for xcopy deployment. My questions are:

- Would I run into any issues about one application locking the DLLs and other application not being able to access and such?
- Would the answer change if we are running in IIS 7 or 7.5 instead of IIS 6?

Comment: have you find a solution? i have same problem!